# to create a table from multiple tables without affecting datawarehouse

Tags: qlikview

I want to create a table in qlikview from multiple tables without affecting the datawarhouse. Also synthetic keys are found and how to remove them.

```
empLeave:     
LOAD SickLeaveHours ,     
    VacationHours ;     
SQL SELECT SickLeaveHours,     
    VacationHours     
FROM databaseConnection;     



empDetails:      
LOAD BirthDate,     
    EmployeeID ,     
    Gender,      
    Title;      
SQL SELECT BirthDate,     
    EmployeeID,     
    Gender,     
    Title      
FROM databaseConnection;     


empAddress:     
LOAD AddressID,     
    ModifiedDate;     
SQL SELECT AddressID,    
    ModifiedDate     
FROM databaseConnection;     

empDepartment:     
LOAD DepartmentID,     
    GroupName,     
    Name;     
SQL SELECT DepartmentID,     
    GroupName,     
    Name     
FROMdatabaseConnection;      

empRate:    
LOAD PayFrequency,    
    Rate;      
SQL SELECT PayFrequency,     
    Rate     
FROM databaseConnection;     


empshift:     
LOAD EndTime,    
     Name as name,    
     ShiftID,    
     StartTime;    
SQL SELECT EndTime,    
    Name,   
    ShiftID,   
    StartTime    
FROM databaseConnection;    
//need to make newtable with EmployeeiD,ShiftID,Vaccationhours, SickleaveHours,departmentID
```

Required to make  table named as newtable with measures of

```
EmployeeID     
ShiftID    
Rate 
SickLeaveHours     
VacationHours
DepartmentID
```

Comment: With the given fields/tables i cant see how you can create the required table. There is no way to join the tables (no common fields). For example to get the `VacationHours` per employee both tables (`empDetails` and `empLeave`) should be joined/linked on something (ideally employee id or name). The same is applied to the other table. Check the database if these tables have something in common to join on

Comment: You are correct. EmployeedID is the primary key in each tables. Will update the codes too. And i applied left join ,things worked. The problem is id gets duplicated due to modified dates assigned to each employeedid in each tables. Now i need to know how to remove duplicates

Comment: if `ModifiedDate` is not required to be part of the join then just rename all instances of the field (or do not load at all if its not needed in any calculation). For example: `empDetails:      
LOAD EmployeeId, ModifiedDate as EmpDetailes_ModifiedDate ...`

Comment: i tried with that, but prevents loading employeeID. just id 1 is displaced